# Explanation of ".action" extention significance in Struts2 URL

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts-action

This might be a useless or lame question but please explain me this.

In struts2 when we assign an action to a form button and click on that button, that action is called. Now, when the result of the action file is displayed, the URL in browser shows

```
localhost:8080/HelloWorld/ClassName.action
```

Sometimes by default `.action` part doesn't show. But both works the same.

I am required to explain to someone what is significance of this `.action`. Why is that extension shown in URL and is there some specific thing which enables and disables the `.action` in Struts2 URL?

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/strutsproperties.html by default framework will provide .action though you can alter it or remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the default action mapper is used to get the mapping from the request url it uses the action extension to determine the action name part. The action extension could be configured with the constant in `struts.xml` (or `struts.properties`)

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="action,,"/>
```

that is default. In some cases if you need to access the static resources instead of action under the same path you could use the ".action" extension to distinguish action from the static resource. If you don't have or don't use such resources then you could easily suppress it by removing `action` from the configuration above.

Comment: Using `<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=","/>` will give you URLs without the .action and still not interfere with static resources such as CSS, JavaScript, and images.

Comment: Ok...so the concept as a whole is that it is simply an indication by struts2 that "Dude, whatever you're watching on screen, is produced using an ACTION class..." nothing else.
And we can even configure it to show different indication or no indication at all.

Great guys. Thanx a lot for the help.

Comment: @KeyurGolani It depends on what filter mapping is used with the struts2 filter if it used `/*` then yes but it also capable of configuring handling static resources.