# Struts2 success page not getting invoked

Tags: ajax, struts2, oauth-2.0

I am invoking struts2 action from jquery-ajax, the action method method getting invoked properly but unfortunately the action success page is not getting invoked. The js method is the one I use for google OAuth2.0.

**JS :**

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
    console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
    console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
    console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
    console.log("Request sent through ajax jquery");

    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "googlesignup",
            data:"idtoken="+id_token,
            dataType : "text",
            async: false,
            // onSuccess:function(){
            //  console.log("success");
            // }
        });}
```

**struts.xml :**

```
<action name="googlesignup" class="com.msventure.web.actions.SignUpAction" method="googleSignUp">
        <result name="success">/buildprofile.jsp</result>
        <result name="fail">/signup.jsp</result>
        <result name="index">/signup.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/signup.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

**Update :**

1. I just checked, i am setting some cookie value in the action method, the cookies are getting updated in the client.However, the response from the success is buildprofile.jsp, it should be changed but it displays the last page.
2. The response to ajax is now going to the error callback function.

Your suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: It is an ajax request. How do you show response from it?

Comment: @Aleksandr M : Yes, i understand this, i think this is the reason it is not changing, i did a redirect and it is working fine.

Comment: What is the point of ajax if you're doing redirection after that?

Comment: I am not doing ajax...i am redirecting

Comment: Anyway after OAuth, i have to redirect to a page...so i am sending token through redirecting rather than ajax i was doing earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the url is correct action, it seems that `url : "googlesignup"`needs to be some thing like: `url : "googlesignup.action"`, you can test it manually by typing its url in address bar and check if you see the result which is `buildprofile.jsp`.

Second you need to define the correct `success` method to show the final result page. like

```
$.ajax(
      ....
       success: function(result){
        $("#someDiv").html(result);
       }
});
```

Make sure you have a `<div id="someDiv"></div>` in your page.

Comment: Struts2 can use empty extension by default.

Comment: As mentioned by @RomanC if you set the `<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=""/>` you can use `url : "googlesignup"` with no problem

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17570547/573032, and especially the comment by Steven Benitez.

Comment: The url is working fine, my data is getting posted correctly and the action method code is even executed properly. Its just when the action method returns SUCCESS, the jsp page mapped with it is not being displayed.

Comment: @coolmego you may have an error in the jsp file. try to use a simple jsp for example a jsp which only has a text in it.

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi : Thanks for your suggestion.I think the reason is ajax is not able to change the page! I did a redirect and it is working fine.Unfortunately, i am not in front of my system, i will update once i have the code.

Comment: @coolmego when the client ajax request is finished the `success` function is executed, there you can do any thing you want. The sample I have shown you get the result and put it in a DIV. you can do other things for example set `window.location` to make a redirect

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi : Yes,it is true,i was making POST request through ajax and my intention was also page change,i realised redirecting through ajax or through simple window.location depends on the requirement. Thanks to all for your assistance.